# How can I `ssh -X host` into a Windows 7 machine and have Windows apps open in Gnome?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh-tunnel, xorg

How can I `ssh -X host` into a Windows 7 machine and have Windows apps open in Gnome like they would if I were ssh'ing into another Linux machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the closest you could get to a behavior like this would be to use a RDP client, in a seamless-app mode.  I haven't played around with this under Vista/7/2008, but on Windows XP/2003 you needed to install a special seamless agent on the Windows system, then using the standard rdesktop you could start a specific app.

Answer (score 2):

Windows GUI is not displayed using X server, so this will never work. You need to use VNC or remote desktop.